# Undesired button height being calculated using Visual Formatting Language

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, visual-format-language

I have a `UIViewController` with four `UIButtons` (2 x 2) on it that I laid out in interface builder that worked perfectly. I'm going to have a free and ad-supported version of my app, so I need to redo that scene to load based on whether the app is a paid or ad-supported version. Based on that, I'm attempting to use Visual Formatting Language to lay out the view. I'm getting incorrect values for my `UIButton` heights despite accounting for them when I calculate them. I can't figure out my mistake (or omission?).

Here's a screenshot of my interface builder. 
[image]

I do not have constraints on my buttons in interface builder, but I do have `IBOutlets` wired to `MyViewController`. `MyViewController` is in a navigation controller and has a tab bar at the bottom.

I created a method called `layoutButtons` that I call in `viewDidLoad` just after `super.viewDidLoad()`. Here it is:

```
func layoutButtons() {
    // Configure layout constraints

    // Remove interface builder constraints from storyboard
    view.removeConstraints(view.constraints)

    // create array to dump constraints into
    var allConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

    // determine screen size
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

    let navBarRect = navigationController!.navigationBar.frame
    let navBarHeight = navBarRect.height

    let tabBarRect = tabBarController!.tabBar.frame
    let tabBarHeight: CGFloat = tabBarRect.height

    // calculate button width based on screen size

    // padding for left + middle + right = 8.0 + 8.0 + 8.0 = 24.0
    let buttonWidth = (screenSize.width - 24.0) / 2

    /*
    My buttons are extending under the top & bottom layout guides despite accounting
    for them when I set the buttonHeight.
    */

    // padding for top + middle + bottom = 8.0 + 8.0 + 8.0 = 24.0
    let buttonHeight = (screenSize.height - topLayoutGuide.length - bottomLayoutGuide.length - 24.0) / 2

    // create dictionary of metrics
    let metrics = ["buttonWidth": buttonWidth,
        "buttonHeight": buttonHeight,
        "navBarHeight": navBarHeight,
        "tabBarHeight": tabBarHeight,
        "bannerAdWidth": bannerAdWidth,
        "bannerAdHeight": bannerAdHeight]

    // create dictionary of views
    var views: [String : AnyObject] = ["firstButton": firstButton,
        "secondButton": secondButton,
        "thirdButton": thirdButton,
        "fourthButton": fourthButton,
        "topLayoutGuide": topLayoutGuide,
        "bottomLayoutGuide": bottomLayoutGuide]

    let topRowHorizontalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "H:|-[firstButton(buttonWidth)]-[secondButton(buttonWidth)]-|",
        options: [.AlignAllCenterY],
        metrics: metrics,
        views: views)
    allConstraints += topRowHorizontalConstraints

    let bottomRowHorizontalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "H:|-[thirdButton(buttonWidth)]-[fourthButton(buttonWidth)]-|",
        options: [.AlignAllCenterY],
        metrics: metrics,
        views: views)
    allConstraints += bottomRowHorizontalConstraints

    let leftColumnVerticalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "V:|[topLayoutGuide]-[firstButton(buttonHeight)]-[thirdButton(buttonHeight)]-[bottomLayoutGuide]|",
        options: [],
        metrics: metrics,
        views: views)
    allConstraints += leftColumnVerticalConstraints

    let rightColumnVerticalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "V:|[topLayoutGuide]-[secondButton(buttonHeight)]-[fourthButton(buttonHeight)]-[bottomLayoutGuide]|",
        options: [],
        metrics: metrics,
        views: views)
    allConstraints += rightColumnVerticalConstraints

    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(allConstraints)
}
```

I've fiddled with my `buttonHeight` variable, but every iteration I've tried results in the buttons extending under the `topLayoutGuide` and `bottomLayoutGuide`. Here's what it looks like at runtime:

[image]

I welcome any suggestions where to look for my mistake. Thank you for reading.

Comment: Run your method from `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`. In `viewDidLoad` the real size of the view is not yet calculated. Because your height calculation depends on the view height it needs to be called in the correct place.

Comment: Also, what is it you actually want it to look like?

Comment: I'd like all 4 buttons drawn between the navbar and the tabbar.

Comment: why Are you using heights and widths constraints for the buttons? Isn't it ok to make them have equal hieghts and widths instead?

Comment: @Fogmeister Thank you. I tried in `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` without luck.

Comment: @Fogmeister You were right on target re: my problem. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I originally followed a [Ray Wenderlich's Visual Format Language tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/110393/auto-layout-visual-format-language-tutorial) and the tutorial's setup was similar to mine in that the `subViews` were on a storyboard and wired to `MyViewController` with `IBOutlets`.

Out of desperation, I nuked the storyboard and created the `UIButtons` in code. Along the way, I discovered my problem was I was setting the image on the button before it was laid out. **The moral of the story is don't set images on `UIButtons` until they're laid out!**

Below is the code called from a method in my `viewDidLoad` that lays out a 2 x 2 grid of buttons:

```
    // Configure Buttons
    firstButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    // code to customize button

    secondButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    // code to customize button

    thirdButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    // code to customize button

    fourthButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    // code to customize button

    // Add buttons to the subview
    view.addSubview(firstButton)
    view.addSubview(secondButton)
    view.addSubview(thirdButton)
    view.addSubview(fourthButton)

    // create views dictionary
    var allConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

    let views: [String : AnyObject] = ["firstButton": firstButton,
        "secondButton": secondButton,
        "thirdButton": thirdButton,
        "fourthButton": fourthButton,
        "topLayoutGuide": topLayoutGuide,
        "bottomLayoutGuide": bottomLayoutGuide]

    // Calculate width and height of buttons
    // 24.0 = left padding + middle padding + right padding
    let buttonWidth = (screenSize.width - 24.0) / 2
    let buttonHeight = (screenSize.height - topLayoutGuide.length - bottomLayoutGuide.length - 24.0) / 2

    // Create a dictionary of metrics
    let metrics = ["buttonWidth": buttonWidth,
    "buttonHeight" : buttonHeight]

    let topVerticalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "V:|[topLayoutGuide]-[firstButton(buttonHeight)]",
        options: [],
        metrics: metrics,
        views: views)
    allConstraints += topVerticalConstraints

    let topRowHorizontalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "H:|-[firstButton(buttonWidth)]-[secondButton(==firstButton)]-|",
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllCenterY,
        metrics: metrics,
        views: views)
    allConstraints += topRowHorizontalConstraints

    let bottomRowHorizontalContraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "H:|-[thirdButton(buttonWidth)]-[fourthButton(==thirdButton)]-|",
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllCenterY,
        metrics: metrics,
        views: views)
    allConstraints += bottomRowHorizontalContraints

    let leftColumnVerticalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "V:[firstButton]-[thirdButton(==firstButton)]-[bottomLayoutGuide]-|",
        options: [],
        metrics: metrics,
        views: views)
    allConstraints += leftColumnVerticalConstraints

    let rightColumnVerticalConstriants = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "V:[secondButton(buttonHeight)]-[fourthButton(==secondButton)]-[bottomLayoutGuide]-|",
        options: [],
        metrics: metrics,
        views: views)
    allConstraints += rightColumnVerticalConstriants

    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(allConstraints)

    // ** DON'T SET IMAGES ON THE BUTTONS UNTIL THE BUTTONS ARE LAID OUT!!!**
    firstButton.imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    firstButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "first.png"), forState: .Normal)

    secondButton.imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    secondButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "second.png"), forState: .Normal)

    thirdButton.imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    thirdButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "third.png"), forState: .Normal)

    fourthButton.imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    fourthButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "fourth.png"), forState: .Normal)
```